# electron child-process is not killed as expected

Tags: python, node.js, process, electron, child-process

I use `'child_process'` to spawn a python process, and try to kill it with `pythonTrain.kill();`.  However, even the function truly is called, python process is still running. Python file contains packages including numpy, pytorch, tensorboard and scipy. Code related is as below:

code to spawn python process

```js
let pythonTrain = null;
let tensorboardProcess = null;

ipcMain.on('start-training', (event, configPath, modelNameValue) => {
    if (pythonTrain) {
        return;
    }

    pythonTrain = spawn("python_env/Scripts/python.exe",
        ["./vits/train.py", "-c", configPath, "-m", modelNameValue],
        { env: { PYTHONIOENCODING: 'UTF-8' } });

    const logdir = `models/${modelNameValue}/`; //日志目录
    startTensorboard(logdir, event.sender);

    pythonTrain.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        event.sender.send('python-train-data', data.toString());
    });

    pythonTrain.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        event.sender.send('python-train-error', data.toString());
    });

    pythonTrain.on('close', (code) => {
        event.sender.send('python-train-exit', code);
        pythonTrain = null;
    });
});
```

code to spawn tensorboard process

```js
const startTensorboard = function (logdir, sender) {
    if (tensorboardProcess) {
        return;
    }

    const pythonEnvPath = path.join(__dirname, './python_env');
    const pythonExecutable = process.platform === 'win32' ? 'python.exe' : 'python';
    const pythonPath = path.join(pythonEnvPath, 'Scripts', pythonExecutable);
    const tensorboardExecutable = 'win32' ? 'tensorboard.exe' : 'tensorboard';
    const tensorboardScriptPath = path.join(pythonEnvPath, 'Scripts', tensorboardExecutable);

    tensorboardProcess = spawn(pythonPath, [tensorboardScriptPath,
        '--logdir', logdir,
        '--reload_interval', '30']);

    tensorboardProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        const output = data.toString();
        console.log(`stderr: ${output}`);
        const urlMatch = output.match(/http:\/\/localhost:\d+/);
        console.log(urlMatch);
        if (urlMatch) {
            sender.send('tensorboard-url', urlMatch[0]);
        }
    });

    tensorboardProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stdout: ${data}`);
    });

    tensorboardProcess.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`TensorBoard process exited with code ${code}`);
    });
}
```

code to kill

```js
app.on('quit', () => {
    if (pythonTrain) {
        console.log('Killing pythonTrain before quitting the app');
        pythonTrain.kill();
    }
    if (tensorboardProcess) {
        console.log('Killing tensorboardProcess before quitting the app');
        tensorboardProcess.kill();
    }
});
```

pid for remaining processes are `49168` and `10884`

electron version is `24.1.2`

even `ps-tree` did nothing to help.

```js
app.on('will-quit', () => {
    // 获取主进程PID
    const mainProcessPid = process.pid;

    // 使用ps-tree模块获取所有子进程的PID
    psTree(mainProcessPid, (err, children) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        // 遍历所有子进程，并向它们发送SIGTERM信号以终止它们
        for (const child of children) {
            console.log('Killing ${child.PID} process before quitting the app');
            process.kill(child.PID, 'SIGTERM');
        }
    });
});
```

even `ps-tree` did nothing to help.

```js
app.on('will-quit', () => {
    // 获取主进程PID
    const mainProcessPid = process.pid;

    // 使用ps-tree模块获取所有子进程的PID
    psTree(mainProcessPid, (err, children) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        // 遍历所有子进程，并向它们发送SIGTERM信号以终止它们
        for (const child of children) {
            console.log('Killing ${child.PID} process before quitting the app');
            process.kill(child.PID, 'SIGTERM');
        }
    });
});
```

I expect all child process to be killed when closing the app.